# Dont match if values repeat in regex

Tags: regex

I want to match using this regex -

```
/\[([1-6],){0,5}[1-6]\]/
```

Some examples that should match are -

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
[2]
[1,2,3]
[1,2]
[1,2]
[1,4,2]
```

A string which is an array of numbers with max possible length as 6. The numbers can only be between 1 and 6. The regex works. But I dont want it to match something like this -

```
[1,2,3,2]
[1,2,2]
[2,2]
```

Basically the numbers shouldnt repeat. If they do, the regex should not match. How do I have to change the regex to achieve this?

Comment: You could use a negative lookahead to check that the same digit does not occur twice `^(?!.*([1-6]).*\1)\[([1-6],){0,5}[1-6]\]` https://regex101.com/r/KjHOWp/1

Comment: Use `\[(?![^][]*(\d)[^][]*\1)(?:[1-6],){0,5}[1-6]\]`. A more generic solution is `\[(?![^][]*\b(\d+)\b[^][]*\b\1\b)(?:[1-6],){0,5}[1-6]\]`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That is the better solution! You could post it and have my vote.

Comment: Ill stick with this one - `^(?!.*(\d).*\1)\[([1-6],){0,5}[1-6]?\]`. But please go ahead and add it as an answer. Ill accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are matching the exact pattern, you can assert using a negative lookahead with a capturing group and backreference `(?!.*(\d).*\1)` that there is no occurrence of the same digit twice.

```
^(?!.*(\d).*\1)\[(?:[1-6],){0,5}[1-6]?\]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ou1xI9/1)

A slightly more optimized pattern could be matching only comma's and digits `[,\d]*` instead of using `.*`

```
^\[(?![\d,]*(\d)[\d,]*\1)(?:[1-6],){0,5}[1-6]?\]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zHBVbx/1)